# Need help auto reorganizing facebook message HTML?

Tags: javascript, html, facebook

I need to reorganize the messages in this facebook messenger HTML by date in descending order. Can someone help me write javascript to accomplish this?

Here is a dummy version of the Facebook message HTML. I don't want to show the actual message I am trying to reorganize because it is thousands of messages long.

https://github.com/LordRorek/Facebook-messenger

Comment: We aren't here to do all of the leg work and write code for you.

Comment: I just am on a time crunch and don't have very much time to do this.

Comment: that is the worst excuse. we all have stuff to do ;)

Answer (score 1):

You need to convert:

> Friday, June 23, 2017 at 2:58pm EDT

to this format:

> Friday 23 Dec 2017 2:58:00 EDT

This will do it:

```
var str = "Friday, June 23, 2017 at 2:58pm EDT";
var date = str.replace("at ", " ").replace("pm", ":00").replace(", ", " ").replace(",", " ").replace("  ", " ").replace("  ", " ").split(" ");
var res = date[0]+" "+date[2]+" "+date[1]+" "+date[3]+" "+date[4]+" "+date[5];
```

Then you can use this to get the number of milliseconds since January 1, 1970, 00:00:00 UTC :

```
console.log(Date.parse('res'));
//1498201080000
```

Use that number for indexing the messages.